# JQuery / XML - problem with & character in XML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, urlencode

I'm trying to parse an XML document that has an attribute called "link" which provides a URL string. The problem is, whenever the URL string includes an & symbol - for example:

```
http://www.site.com/segment/page.html#/?view=viewName&model=4
```

The xml parsing breaks and won't parse anything beyond this node. Here's my code:

```
parseVehicles: function(xmlNode) {  
    $j(xmlNode).children().each(function() {
        console.log(supertree.vehicleCount);
        supertree.vehicleCount++;
    });
},
```

How do I keep this from breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XML looks like this:

```
<foo link="http://www.site.com/segment/page.html#/?view=viewName&model=4" />
```

Then that's simply invalid XML. The `&` should be escaped:

```
<foo link="http://www.site.com/segment/page.html#/?view=viewName&amp;model=4" />
```

Fix whatever's creating the invalid XML.